# Linq Query Works on Web Application But throws error when using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, linq-to-entities, nunit

I have a method on my service which selects data as below using Linq To Entities:

```
  var test = _repository.DbSet().
            .Select(t => new CustomClass
            {
                Count = t.Count.ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

It works on my `asp.net mvc` application, but it throws the following error when calling the method through `Nunit` :

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how your code works in production but as per [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exception-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-tostring):

> This exception mainly occurs when we query SQL database using entity
>   framework. The problem is that you are calling ToString in a LINQ to
>   Entities query (IQueryable to IEnumrable). That means the parser is
>   trying to convert the ToString call into its equivalent SQL (which
>   isn't possible...hence the exception).

You can fix it by using `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()`:

```
var test = _repository.DbSet().
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(t => new CustomClass
        {
            Count = t.Count.ToString(),
        }).ToList();
```

Based on the [supported link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exception-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-tostring) you can use [SqlFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DbFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx)
 to have this functionality without a full table scan.